# How to select from DB only 5 records. Use MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql select:

```
SELECT employee.name, employee.surname, department.name FROM employee INNER JOIN deparment 
ON employee.id_department=department.id WHERE department.name = 'security'
```

But I wanna select **only 5 records**. If I can do this using the SQL tools?

And If I wana select **>= 5 records** (more than 5 records)?

Comment: Use limit in you query.

Comment: What do you mean my greater than equal to 5 - Your SQL statement is the correct answer, if there are more records it will display greater than 5 records and if there are 5 records it will display 5 no need to limit.

Comment: @Murtaza I wanna select more than 5 records. That is if my table have 10 records, I wanna to see them. And if my table have 3 records, I don't wanna to see them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the SQL

```
SELECT employee.name, employee.surname, department.name 
FROM employee INNER JOIN deparment
ON employee.id_department=department.id 
WHERE department.name = 'security'
LIMIT 5;
```

To know more about [LIMIT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

---

### Edit

I believe **>= 5 records** means leaving first 5 records and get another 5.

```
SELECT employee.name, employee.surname, department.name 
FROM employee INNER JOIN deparment
ON employee.id_department=department.id 
WHERE department.name = 'security'
LIMIT 5,5;
```

Comment: And if I wanna select more than 5 records from the entire table?

Comment: Just increase the number to whatsoever number of records you wanted to fetch

Comment: Let say you wanted to fetch 7 records then use `LIMIT 7`

Comment: Here is another link know more about [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT employee.name, employee.surname, department.name FROM employee INNER JOIN deparment 
ON employee.id_department=department.id WHERE department.name = 'security'

limit 5;
```

Comment: Ok. And If a wanna select >= 5 records?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT employee.name
     , employee.surname
     , department.name 
FROM employee 
INNER JOIN deparment 
     ON employee.id_department=department.id
WHERE department.name = 'security'
LIMIT 5 , 5 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT employee.name, employee.surname, department.name FROM employee INNER JOIN deparment 
ON employee.id_department=department.id WHERE department.name = 'security'
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT `employee.name`
     , `employee.surname`
     , `dept.name` 
     FROM employee 
     INNER JOIN deparment as dept
     ON `employee.id_department`=`dept.id`
     WHERE `department.name` = 'security'
     LIMIT 5 , 5 ;